# Symfony2 - listeners on doctrine / orm

Tags: symfony

What is the best way to have an event that fires after a record is inserted in Symfony2 / Doctrine?

Answer (score 10):

First, register a service as a Doctrine event listener:

`app/config.yml`:

```
services:
    foo.listener:
        class: Vendor\FooBundle\BarClass
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, method: onPostPersist }
```

Then in your listener class, define an `onPostPersist` method (or whatever you named the method in the config) that takes a `Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs` argument:

```
public function onPostPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    // do stuff with the entity here
}
```

Note that you can't pass an instance of EntityManager to the listener class, because $eventArgs contains a reference to it, and doing so will throw a CircularReferenceException.

Doctrine Project documentation [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events). Symfony Project documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) (out of date, but included for reference)/

Comment: I'm doing this exact same thing, but am trying to include a reference to the securityContext object in my listener.  I added: arguments: ["@security.context"] to my yml file but when i add the $securityContext object into my constructor I get a circular ref error. Any ideas? I am using the FOSUserBundle and that shows in the error i receive.

Comment: Here's the error i receive. ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "security.context", path: "profiler_listener -> profiler -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_manager -> doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> my.listener".

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting the container itself instead of the security context. with FOS_USER, security.context depends on your listener (EM) and your listener requires security.context.

```
<service id="foo.listener" class="%foo.listener.class%">
  <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
  <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="postPersist" method="fooMethod" />
</service>
```

By the way, at least in XML, the method name does not seem to be working, by default it call the method 'postPersist' instead and ignore whatever method name you give (fooMethod); Please let me know if that's the case with YAML config, too, or I am just wrong.